# PhpStorm warning PHP variable might not have been defined

Tags: php, phpstorm

Consider:

```
<?php
  //  $smith = "";
  $submit ="button_a";

  if($submit == "button_a") {
      $smith = "button_a";
  }
    elseif($submit == "button_b"){
      $smith = "button_b";
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <?php echo($smith);  ?>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

PhpStorm provides a flag for each file: Red - Errors, Yellow - Warning, Green - OK.

The PHP code above the header will assign a value to *$smith*. In the body, I get a warning on $smith saying that it might be undefined. If I declare all of the variable at the top of the PHP code, ($smith = "";) it is happy (no warning).

Is there something that I should be doing to prevent these warnings?

I don't like the idea of attaching the comment to each one saying to not check it and I don't want to turn them all off.

This happens a lot when I include my *db_login.php* file which defines four or five variables.  I have different *db_login.php* files for [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants), [MAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAMP), and the real hose.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would thoroughly recommend tho always declaring/initialising a variable before any use... makes debugging so much easier.

Comment: ... and not to use global variables for settings (e.g. db details etc -- static class for a help) -- if it's your own code, of course :)

Answer (score 17):

You can tell PhpStorm to ignore undefined variables reports if *require* on include statements are located in the same execution flow before the variable access.

You'll find it in *'Undefined variable' - Ignore 'include' and 'require' statements*. It is enabled by default, so you should disable it.

[image]

*Note: The setting is in menu *File* → *Settings* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) → *Project Settings* → *Inspections* → *PHP* → *Undefined* → *Undefined variable*

Comment: Where are these settings?

Comment: File > Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) > Project Settings > Inspections > PHP > Undefined > Undefined variable

Comment: Thanks Kobra. @Dreen: pls update the answer, as screenshot really lacks context.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, there are two things you can do to get rid of this warning. What you said:

```
$smith = "";
if($submit == "button_a") {
    $smith = "button_a";
}
elseif($submit == "button_b"){
    $smith = "button_b";
}
```

Or check if it's set when you print it:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $smith)) {
        echo($smith);
    }
?>
```

However, this is just a warning, and it is letting you know that there is a condition that `$smith` won't be defined (when `$submit` isn't `"button_a"` and isn't `"button_b"`). If that condition were to occur, you would be printing `$smith` when it wasn't set, which could be a bug in your script.

Comment: PHPSTORM is smarter than I had thought. If I change elseif to else so that all paths through the code assign a value, it is happy.  What about my db_login include file that defines database, user, password, table, etc.  Any way to make it "look into" the include file so that I don't have to predefine them all?

Comment: Because then there's no conditions that exist in which `$smith` wouldn't be defined. It's actually helpful (IMO), as it's telling you that a condition exists where you'd be accessing a variable that hasn't been defined. You'd only get this info from PHP if you executed the script with the "bug" conditions (i.e. where `$submit` isn't `button_a` or `button_b`). For your include file issues, see Dreen's answer below.