# Notice: Variable seems to be uninitialized

Tags: php

For some reason I am getting this notice in my code.

> Variable $conn seems to be uninitialized

I don't understand why I'm seeing this notice.  I think I'm including my `include` in the right place.

```
Class Calendar {

  public function show() {
    include './includes/dbconn.php';
    include_once './includes/functions.php';

    for ($i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++) {

      // Create days in a week
      for ($j=1;$j<=7;$j++) {

        $cal_date = (string)$this->currentDate;
        $tutor_date = display_tutor_schedule($conn,$cal_date);

        if(isset($tutor_date[$j]['date'])) {
          $content .= $this->_showDay($i*7+$j, $tutor_date[$j]['date']);
        }
        else {
          $content .= $this->_showDay($i*7+$j, 0);
        }
      }
      $content .="</tr>";
    }
  }

}
```

My `$conn` variable is coming from `include './includes/dbconn.php';`. Since I am not getting any PHP database error, such as "Not connected to the database" or something like that, I assume that my connection is right.

#### functions.php

```
function display_tutor_schedule($conn,$tutor_date) {

  $query = "select * from [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE] "
          . "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TUTOR] "
          . "ON [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].tutor_id = [dbo].[TUTOR].tutor_id "
          . "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[STATUS] "
          . "ON [dbo].[STATUS].status_id = [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].status_id "
          . "WHERE [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].date = '$tutor_date' " ;

  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

  $i = 0;
  $appt_detail = array();
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
      $appt_detail[$i]['date']         = $row['date'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['t_shedule_id'] = $row['t_shedule_id'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['start_time']   = $row['start_time'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['end_time']     = $row['end_time'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['tutor_fname']  = $row['tutor_fname'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['tutor_lname']  = $row['tutor_lname'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['status_name']  = $row['status_name'];
      $appt_detail[$i]['status_id']    = $row['status_id'];

      $i++;
  }
  return $appt_detail;
}
```

#### my_class.php

```
<?php
    $calendar = new Calendar();
    echo $calendar->show();
?>
```

#### dbconn.php

```
$serverName = "myserver";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "my_database", "UID" => "user", "PWD" => "pwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Are you using PHPStorm?

Comment: We have no idea what `/includes/functions.php` contains/does so there is no sane way to guess a solution.

Comment: @MahmoudTantawy nop, netbeans

Comment: @PeeHaa the issue is in `/includes/dbconn.php` not in `/includes/functions.php`

Comment: Looks like an issue with netbeans and phpstorm, check https://netbeans.org/projects/php/lists/users/archive/2013-03/message/49 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751330/phpstorm-warning-php-variable-might-not-have-been-defined

Comment: @ArielMaduro well considering you haven't shared either it's hard to guess either way

Comment: Where does said error come from? Does PHP tell you there is a problem or your IDE? Did you run the code?

Comment: @PeeHaa I use the same connection with all my projects, the only different in this project is that I am doing a `class` I've never use my connections or `include` anything in a class...So, I thought this issue is more about my class than my files

Comment: so, where are you initializing that class? the error it's throwing says it all. *Variable $conn seems to be **uninitialized***

Comment: The error PHP gives you for an undefined variable includes all of the information needed to debug the problem. For example, it will give you the name of the variable that was not defined (which you have included here `$conn`), as well as the exact line number on which the undefined variable triggered the error (which have not included here), and the exact file in which the error was triggered (which have also not included here).

Comment: @ArielMaduro we dont care about `my_class.php` we wanna see `dbConn.php`

Comment: @Sherif the line is inluded there `$tutor_date = display_tutor_schedule($conn,$cal_date);`

Comment: @ArielMaduro what about `$weeksInMonth` and `$content` where are there defined

Comment: @Fred-ii- Since I thought the error was in the class, I just try to write a small example here so people could provide me some answers.  Sometimes when people see a lot of code they don't like to read questions..so I just tried to make my code as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) or [PhpStorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpStorm), then this might be IDE issue.

Check https://netbeans.org/projects/php/lists/users/archive/2013-03/message/49 and *[PhpStorm warning PHP variable might not have been defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751330/phpstorm-warning-php-variable-might-not-have-been-defined)*

However, it is advisable that you show us the files you include to check them.

Comment: He says "Since I am not getting any php database error such as Not connected to the database or something like that, I assume that my connection is right."

Comment: Looks like he is getting the error in the IDE and when running the code everything is fine, not sure though!

Comment: The first link is broken *"Not found. Page not found."*

Answer (score -1):

Don't use includes or global for your variables. It's bad.

Instead you should be using classes:

```
class Database {

    private $conn;

    public function __construct(){
        $serverName = "myserver";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "my_database",
                                "UID" => "user",
                                "PWD" => "pwd");
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    }

    public function  get_connection(){
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

**Calendar.php**

```
class Calendar
{
    private $conn;
    public $weeksInMonth;

    function __construct($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }


    public function show()
    {
        $content = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->weeksInMonth; $i++) {
            //Create days in a week
            for ($j = 1; $j <= 7; $j++) {
                $cal_date = (string)$this->currentDate;
                $tutor_date = display_tutor_schedule($cal_date);

                if (isset($tutor_date[$j]['date'])) {
                    $content .= $this->_showDay($i * 7 + $j, $tutor_date[$j]['date']);
                } else {
                    $content .= $this->_showDay($i * 7 + $j, 0);
                }
            }
            $content .= "</tr>";
        }
        return $content;
    }

    function display_tutor_schedule($tutor_date)
    {
        $query = "select * from [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE] "
            . "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TUTOR] "
            . "ON [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].tutor_id = [dbo].[TUTOR].tutor_id "
            . "LEFT JOIN [dbo].[STATUS] "
            . "ON [dbo].[STATUS].status_id = [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].status_id "
            . "WHERE [dbo].[TUTOR_SCHEDULE].date = '$tutor_date' ";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $query);

        $appt_detail = array();
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
            $appt_detail[] = $row;
        }
        return $appt_detail;
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
$db = new Database();
$conn = $db->get_connection();
$calendar = new Calendar($conn);
$calendar->weeksInMonth = 4;
echo $calendar->show();
```

Comment: Although you are correct this doesn't in any way actually answer OP.

Comment: @PeeHaa with this code he won't get `Variable $conn seems to be uninitialized`

Comment: With the code `<?php echo 'yay';` he also wouldn't get the error. Still doesn't answer OP.

Comment: @PeeHaa like you said Im correct, and if my answer helps OP to clear the error, then Im happy. Dont care what you think

Answer (score -2):

Since the variable is first initialized in the dbconn.php, the IDE might not recognize it. Insert

```
 $conn = null;
```

after the line

```
public function show() {
```

Comment: The file is included in the scope of where it is called.

Comment: @PeeHaa exactly, because it is my scope I though I wouldn't have any problem =/

Comment: @ArielMaduro what gives you the error? Is it when you run the php code or is it an IDE warning?

Comment: Have you.... like... idunno.... actually ran the code to check whether it is just your IDE getting confused instead of an actual error in your code? Because it sounds like @MahmoudTantawy is pretty much in the money.

Comment: The IDE might not check if the variable is defined in the included file. So if you don't get a warning when executing the code, there is no problem.

Comment: @ArielMaduro You may do the following:
Include $conn = null; before including the dbconn.php.