# variable scope method{foreach{if(){variable}else{}}}

Tags: php, variables, scope, arrayobject

Why does this work? I thought variables would only be visible within scope... Or is the scope method?

1) Ideally: $variable-name would be defined first step with foreach... but how?
2) why is $variable defined in the if clause accessible in the whole foreach block?
3) in PHPStorm I get an compile error, but the code works...

ArrayObject __construct:

```
// read JSON
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {

    if ($jsonIterator->getDepth()===0){

        $variable = new Preguntas_Educacion_V1($key);
        $this->offsetSet($variable->getColumn(),$variable);
    } else if ($jsonIterator->getDepth()===1){

        //Reflection!!! call setter dynamically by Val

        $function="set".ucfirst($key);
        $variable->$function($val);
    } else if ($jsonIterator->getDepth()===2){
            //Respuestas array
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: If it's been set in a previous iteration, it's still defined in the next iteration (its defined until the end of the script unless `unset()` or set equal to null), even if a different condition is met. If you want to read about scopes, [this is a good thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/4535200) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. ... However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced.*"<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)</sup>

Thus once the variable is defined (in the *foreach* loop) it will be visible in subsequent iterations.

You can disable warnings about undefined variables in PHPStorm. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751397/1575353).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php</sub>